# Does Neo4j 3.1.2 use index with regex search in cypher?

Tags: neo4j

This query takes long to return the data. Anything wrong with the search?

```
MATCH (a:Amount)
WHERE a.accountNumber=~'(^0?i)244.*' 
RETURN a
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use a regex expression, you are not using any index, you are doing a full scan by label.

You can check it by making an `EXPLAIN` of your query.

You should consider to use the following keywords, they are index compatible : `CONTAINS`, `STARTS WITH`, `ENDS WITH`